# Uib date picker pop up , restrict text box value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using uib datepicker pop up , and the date text box value can be cleared and can be any of values , how to restrict it ? it can be cleared but no values can be typed into it.

```
Demo Plunker 
https://plnkr.co/edit/TXFAieldRjUFZJL9IHw1?p=preview
```

Comment: do you want that user can not type anything just can select the date?

Comment: here it is like after selecting the date he can click on the input (pop up comes ) and can clear the date / type anything he wants.